# $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-guiを実行すると、gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.と出て、Traceback (most recent call last):と出ます。

Tags: linux, debian, apt

こんばんは。夜分遅くに失礼いたします。
お世話になります。
Debian 10のbashシェルで`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui`を実行しますと、下記のメッセージが出てきます。

```sh
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpaa42a0x0/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpaa42a0x0/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EFD5FA852F20733F: public key "Launchpad fprint" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 491, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 449, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 447, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):`に続くエラーメッセージと、
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'`の解決法をご教授願ます。

追記1

[How to enable fingerprint scanner support on Linux](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-fingerprint-scanner-support-on-linux/)

上記リンクを参考にしたのですが、、
間違えて下記のコマンドを実行しましたら、`sudo apt-get update`を実行しました際に大量のエラーが出てまいりました。
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv EFD5FA852F20733F`

下記がエラーの内容です。

```sh
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InReleaseHit:2 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster InRelease                            Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease  yusuke@debian:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                                          
Ign:3 http://ftp.jp.d

（長い空行）

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.jaist.ac.jp_debian_dists_buster_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_buster_updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 150.65.7.130 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/security.debian.org_debian-security_dists_stretch_updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 133.5.166.3 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_fingerprint_fingerprint-gui_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/packagecloud.io_slacktechnologies_slack_debian_dists_jessie_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/Release.gpg  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  At least one invalid signature was encountered.
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

解決法をご教授願います。

追記2
`No space left on device`というエラーメッセージが出ておりましたので、@metropolis 様のおっしゃるように`sudo apt clean`を実行致しました。

その後、`sudo apt update`を実行しますと、下記のエラー？が出てきました。

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/debian buster-updates InRelease         
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                                                          
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                                         
Ign:5 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:6 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                            
Hit:7 http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:9 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:10 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                               
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done
```

Ign(無視)と出てきておりますが、`/etc/apt/sources.list`と`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list`と
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list.d`を見ましても、

`http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease`
`http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease`

上記の２つの行は見当たりませんでした。どのようにすれば解決できるのでしょうか。
ご教授願ます。

[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/227636?modal=q-comp)にもマルチポストさせていただきますのでご容赦願います。

Comment: すみません、PPA(Personal Package Archive) のリポジトリは Ubuntu distribution のみで利用可能なものです。Debian10 で fingerprint-gui をインストールする手順については [How to enable fingerprint scanner support on Linux](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/enable-fingerprint-scanner-support-on-linux/) の `Debian 10` の項目を参照して下さい。

Comment: > metropolis様 いえいえ、むしろ初心者の私に毎回教えてくださりありがとうございます。間違えて`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv EFD5FA852F20733F`を実行したせいか、`sudo apt-get update`を実行しました際に大量のエラーが出てきます。

Comment: エラーメッセージに `No space left on device` と表示されているのですが、ディスクの空き容量がほとんどないのではないでしょうか…

Comment: > metropolis様ディスクを追加いたします。というか、、パソコンが7年型落ちですので、、そろそろ買い換えないとですね。

Comment: `sudo apt clean` を実行すれば少しは空き容量が増えるかもしれません。

Comment: @metropolis 様 `sudo apt clean`を実行しましたところ、`sudo apt update`を実行しましたらエラーが一つも出ずに終了致しました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: @metropolis 様 エラーが一つも出なかったと思いましたら、、Ign(無視)という行が出てきました、、

Comment: [What does 'Ign', `Get` or 'Hit' mean when running an apt-get update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294525/) を読んでみて下さい。

Comment: @metropolis 様　拝読しました。Ignは気にしなくても良さそうですね。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui という PPA は Ubuntu 向けに作られているので、Debian で無理矢理使おうとしてエラーに繋がっていそうです。

https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian より引用：

> Repositories that can create a FrankenDebian if used with Debian Stable:
>
> - Debian *testing* release (currently *bullseye*)
> - Debian *unstable* release (also known as *sid*)
> - Ubuntu, Mint or other derivative repositories are **not** compatible with Debian!
> - Ubuntu PPAs

一応同様のエラーメッセージに対応する類似質問として [Ubuntu の鍵サーバーを使うように勧めるもの](https://superuser.com/q/1262928/680903)や [gnupg-agent のインストールを勧めるもの](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44909408/5989200)がありますが、根本的には自分でソースからビルドするのが確実かなと思います（が、現在元々の[ソース](http://www.ullrich-online.cc/fingerprint/)にはアクセスできないようですね……）。

Comment: > nekketsuuu様
アドバイスありがとうございます。色々と試してみてできませんでしたら諦めます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu PPA のリンクを辿っていけば deb パッケージやソースコード (*.tar.xz) も配布されているので、根気があれば手動インストールも試せるかと思います。

Comment: > cubick様 教えていただき感謝です！